# Optimize loops with big datasets Python

Tags: python, mongodb, loops, optimization

It's the first time I go so big with Python so I need some help.

I have a mongodb (or python dict) with the following structure:

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid" : "521b1fabc36b440cbe3a6009" },
  "country": "Brazil",
  "id": "96371952",
  "latitude": -23.815124482000001649,
  "longitude": -45.532670811999999216,
  "name": "coffee",
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 277659258,
      "photos": [
        {
          "created_time": 1376857433,
          "photo_id": "525440696606428630_277659258",
        },
        {
          "created_time": 1377483144,
          "photo_id": "530689541585769912_10733844",
        }
      ],
      "username": "foo"
    },
    {
      "id": 232745390,
      "photos": [
        {
          "created_time": 1369422344,
          "photo_id": "463070647967686017_232745390",
        }
      ],
      "username": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I want to create two files, one with the summaries and the other with the weight of each connection. My loop which works for small datasets is the following:

```
#a is the dataset
data = db.collection.find()
a =[i for i in data]

#here go the connections between the locations
edges = csv.writer(open("edges.csv", "wb"))
#and here the location data
nodes = csv.writer(open("nodes.csv", "wb"))

for i in a:

    #find the users that match
    for q in a:
        if i['_id'] <> q['_id'] and q.get('users') :
            weight = 0
            for user_i in i['users']:
                for user_q in q['users']:
                    if user_i['id'] == user_q['id']:
                        weight +=1
            if weight>0:
                edges.writerow([ i['id'], q['id'], weight])


    #find the number of photos
    photos_number =0
    for p in i['users']:
        photos_number += len(p['photos'])


    nodes.writerow([ i['id'],
                    i['name'],
                    i['latitude'],
                    i['longitude'],
                    len(i['users']),
                    photos_number
                ])
```

The scaling problems: I have 20000 locations, each location might have up to 2000 users, each user might have around 10 photos.

Is there any more efficient way to create the above loops? Maybe Multithreads, JIT, more indexes?
Because if I run the above in a single thread can be up to 20000^2 *2000 *10 results...

So how can I handle more efficiently the above problem?
Thanks

Comment: Styling change: replace `<>` with `!=`. Also, what is in `a`?

Comment: `a` stands for the dict. I updated my question.

Comment: I do not think it stands for the dict. Otherwise `for i in a` would be iterating over the _keys_, so further using key `i['_id']` would generate an error. I suppose it is a list.

Comment: @Tadeck Yes you are correct. Edited with more info

Comment: You have a lot of 'for' loops like 4 nested, that is a performance killer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@YuchenXie and @PaulMcGuire's suggested microoptimizations probably aren't your main problem, which is that you're looping over 20,000 x 20,000 = 400,000,000 pairs of entries, and then have an inner loop of 2,000 x 2,000 user pairs. That's going to be slow.

Luckily, the inner loop can be made much faster by pre-caching `set`s of the user ids in `i['users']`, and replacing your inner loop with a simple set intersection. That changes an `O(num_users^2)` operation that's happening in the Python interpreter to an `O(num_users)` operation happening in C, which should help. (I just timed it with lists of integers of size 2,000; on my computer, it went from 156ms the way you're doing it to 41µs this way, for a 4,000x speedup.)

You can also cut off half your work of the main loop over pairs of locations by noticing that the relationship is symmetric, so there's no point in doing both `i = a[1]`, `q = a[2]` and `i = a[2]`, `q = a[1]`.

Taking these and @PaulMcGuire's suggestions into account, along with some other stylistic changes, your code becomes (caveat: untested code ahead):

```
from itertools import combinations, izip

data = db.collection.find()
a = list(data)

user_ids = [{user['id'] for user in i['users']} if 'users' in i else set()
            for i in a]

with open("edges.csv", "wb") as f:
    edges = csv.writer(f)
    for (i, i_ids), (q, q_ids) in combinations(izip(a, user_ids), 2):
        weight = len(i_ids & q_ids)
        if weight > 0:
            edges.writerow([i['id'], q['id'], weight])
            edges.writerow([q['id'], i['id'], weight])

with open("nodes.csv", "wb") as f:
    nodes = csv.writer(f)
    for i in a:
        nodes.writerow([
            i['id'],
            i['name'],
            i['latitude'],
            i['longitude'],
            len(i['users']),
            sum(len(p['photos']) for p in i['users']), # total number of photos
        ])
```

Hopefully this should be enough of a speedup. If not, it's possible that @YuchenXie's suggestion will help, though I'm doubtful because the stdlib/OS is fairly good at buffering that kind of thing. (You might play with the buffering settings on the file objects.)

Otherwise, it may come down to trying to get the core loops out of Python (in Cython or handwritten C), or giving PyPy a shot. I'm doubtful that'll get you any huge speedups now, though.

You may also be able to push the hard weight calculations into Mongo, which might be smarter about that; I've never really used it so I don't know.

Comment: Thanks that's what I really wanted. It really speeds up things. I however get a `TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()` in the `sum(len(p['photos'] for p in i['users'])),` line. Does this mean I have no `p['photos']` for that user? Thanks again.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, that's a typo: should be `sum(len(p['photos']) for p in i['users'])`. With the paren in the other place, it was trying to take the length of the generator object, rather than adding up the length of each list.

Answer (score 2):

The bottle neck is disk I/O.

It should be much faster when you merge the results and use one or several `writerows` call instead of many `writerow`.

Answer (score 1):

Does collapsing this loop:

```
photos_number =0
for p in i['users']:
    photos_number += len(p['photos'])
```

down to:

```
photos_number = sum(len(p['photos']) for p in i['users'])
```

help at all?

Your weight computation:

```
        weight = 0
        for user_i in i['users']:
            for user_q in q['users']:
                if user_i['id'] == user_q['id']:
                    weight +=1
```

should also be collapsible down to:

```
        weight = sum(user_i['id'] == user_q['id'] 
                        for user_i,user_q in product([i['users'],q['users']))
```

Since True equates to 1, summing all the boolean conditions is the same as counting all the values that are True.

Comment: Why should it? It looks like putting loop in one line and relying on `sum()` instead of addition. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are moving the iteration code into Python's compiled C library instead of grinding through the loop in Python bytecode. Likewise for using product instead of an explicit for loop inside a for loop. Of course, these are just blind stabs at optimizing, more formal profiling will show you where the real bottlenecks are.